# cannot read Cookie that was set with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a php that sets:

```
setrawcookie('psd_susenka', rawurlencode("cookie_value"), time() + (86400 * 365));
```

I even tried the long version with paths, domains, and switches (http only and secure, both with false values)

then, after reloading the page I have jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert(document.cookies);
})
```

If the only cookie set is "psd_susenka" then I get alert with "Undefined".
If I set another cookies with `$.cookie("test", something, { expires: 365 });` then the alert writes only the cookies set via jquery

So what is wrong with the php code? Or maybe something wrong with the jquery alert?
I got `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>` loaded and the cookie is manualy checked in chrome so it exists.

Comment: are you setting the cookies in ajax or what?

Comment: If you go to the Application tab in Chrome Inspector, can you see the cookie? Is it secure?

Comment: I recommend moving away from cookies and using sessions and ajax

Comment: @LucaColonnello thanks for suggestion. It is not secure but it is HTTP only even when it's specified in php not to be `setrawcookie('psd_susenka', rawurlencode($psw), time() + (86400 * 365), NULL , NULL , NULL , 0);`

Comment: Instead of setting those optional parameters to null, try just skipping them, like `setrawcookie('psd_susenka', rawurlencode($psw), time() + (86400 * 365), ,  ,  , FALSE);` also, why are you not just using `setcookie` instead of manually url encoding the cookie value?

Comment: Well, I can't skip arguments in PHP - at least I thought that.
I did try ´setcookie´. This example with 'setrawcookie' is just a second try and I kept the code that way

Comment: This is really nerve-wracking. I know I just learned about argument skipping in the past few weeks, and now I am only finding evidence that neither php nor JavaScript support it. But I don't read the docs for any other languages, so I must have dreamed it.

Comment: Make sure you don't output anything before calling - `setrawcookie() and setcookie()`. Be sure as well you don't have character(s) before `<?php`. Output before those functions and tag can cause cookie setting to fail.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a typo.

Try `document.cookie` instead `document.cookies`.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

P.S. `document.cookie` is part of WebAPI (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). This is not part of jQuery and not part of JavaScript. JavaScript (also jQuery, because it works only with JavaScript) is able to work with WebAPI.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Tried it still return only the cookies set via javascript not the php one.

Comment: as @Luca Colonnello suggested I checked it with Chrome Application tab and the cookie set via PHP is Http Only even when I set it to false `setrawcookie('psd_susenka', rawurlencode($psw), time() + (86400 * 365), NULL , NULL , NULL , 0);`

Comment: Nerd. (I said it)

Comment: @loqan Your code works for me, checked repeatedly.
Perhaps not so you do something.
Check on the new page, write these simplest operations anew.